# WebAudioContext: Converting a .WAV blob from FFMPEG.Wasm returns a Float32Array with all 0's with decodechannel(0)

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm trying to convert an audio blob Into a Float32Array to use for Whisper.cpp, but whenever I do that, the final result is a Float32Array with all values being 0. The Audio Buffer recognizes correctly the duration of the video, the number of channels, and I can hear the audio file in an audio tag. I believe my issue is related to `getChannelData(0)`

My code looks like this:

```js
        const audio_data = ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'output_audio.wav');
        show_audio = true;
        const blob = new Blob([audio_data.buffer], { type: 'audio/wav' })
        src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        // Convert the Audio Stream to a Buffer for Whisper
        const audioContext = new AudioContext({
            sampleRate: 16000,
            channelCount: 1,
            echoCancellation: false,
            autoGainControl:  true,
            noiseSuppression: true,
        });

        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        let buffer;

        fileReader.onloadend = () => {
            buffer = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result);
            console.log(buffer)

            audioContext.decodeAudioData(buffer.buffer).then(function(decodedData) {
                console.log(decodedData)

                var offlineContext = new OfflineAudioContext(decodedData.numberOfChannels, decodedData.length, decodedData.sampleRate);
                var source = offlineContext.createBufferSource();
                source.connect(offlineContext.destination);
                source.start(0);

                offlineContext.startRendering().then(function(renderedBuffer) {
                    console.log(renderedBuffer)
                    console.log(renderedBuffer.getChannelData(0))
                    BUFFER_AUDIO_DATA = renderedBuffer.getChannelData(0)
                })

        })

        }

        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

I tried passing the buffer data directly without using fileReader, I tried using `audio_data.buffer.slice(0);` in terms it can help. I also tried passing creating an AudioContext with no parameters. I also attempted the following

`BUFFER_AUDIO_DATA = Float32Array.from(audio_data.buffer);`

But the output was again 0

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I appreciate your help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The last part of your code which uses an `OfflineAudioContext` seems to be not necessary. Try reading the audio data directly from the decoded `AudioBuffer`.

```
console.log(decodedData.getChannelData(0));
```